# How to stop/don't requireJS overide my "scripts" -- It is possible?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc, jsp, requirejs

When I use requireJS and it will make overide and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: myScript is not defined
```

I know requireJS will run after my script loaded, that is only way i have to define my script in requireJS too? (too much script, not only my code), I keep find a smart way to do, please give any suggest.

1.impossible define my script in requireJS, too much script.

This is my JSP load my script

```
<spring:eval expression="T(xxx.web.entity.WebResource).get('page/template/scripts/*.json')" var="pageScripts"/>
```

This is what I using requireJS

```
<script src="Scripts/require/require.js" data-main="Scripts/require/main"></script>
```